# How to share files in Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion

## Background:

It is troublesome to upload some files to Stack exchange. A possibility is to give some Google Drive or Dropbox URL but it maybe unaccessible to some people. Using the SE Uploader gives some error information like the following:

[image]

This results in the add-on not being usable in China or other places with firewalls.

Using `Databin` is very very slow and limits your file size.

## Question:

Is there a good method to share files in Stack Exchange?

Comment: Should this (very good) question belong on meta?

Comment: @QuantumDot How to transfer this post to meta?

Comment: Related: [Upload large amount of data more easily](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1351/18476)

Answer (score 7):

Thank for the J.M.'s and SqRoots' help in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/128688/how-to-call-picture-bed-api),I make a function to do this,one can use it encrypt any express in a URL.Now you just share your URL to another:

```
ShareAny[expr_] := 
 Module[{list, imageWidth, imageHeight, n}, 
  list = ToCharacterCode[Compress[expr]];
  {imageWidth, 
    imageHeight} = {If[(n = Ceiling[Sqrt[Length[list]/3]])*(n - 1) > 
      Length[list]/3, n - 1, n], n};
  Print[Style[
    The following expression to share is in your clipboard., 11, 
    Red]]; (CopyToClipboard@#; #) &[
   Defer[Uncompress@*FromCharacterCode@*
      Flatten@*(ImageData[#, "Byte"] &)@*Import][
    ImportString[
      URLFetch["https://sm.ms/api/upload", Method -> "POST", 
       "MultipartElements" -> {{"smfile\"; filename=\"tmp.png", 
           "image/png"} -> 
          ExportString[
           Image[ArrayReshape[list, {imageWidth, imageHeight, 3}], 
            "Byte"], "PNG"]}], "RawJSON"]["data", "url"]]]]
```

There is a example,you can cope with any expression,such as **List**,**Image**,**Graph** or other **local file**, like following

```
list = Range[10^5];
ShareAny[list]
```

[image]

Comment: You can merge the extraction of an `Association[]` entry as `["data", "url"]` instead of `["data"]["url"]`.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks :)

Comment: Why not to use http://imgur.com/ which is associated with StackExchange?

Comment: @Alexey, the OP complains about imgur being inaccessible from behind the Great Firewall unless a VPN is used.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks, never thought that this may be the case. It is not completely clear from the question though.

Comment: Yes, hopefully he'll edit his question to say this, @Alexey.

Comment: @J.M. I'll research imgur.

Comment: @J.M. When I try to call the Imgur API,it will give me a response like "Imgur is temporarily over capacity. Please try again later."Would you be like this?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Can you call the imgur-API?It cost my some time but fail to make it.This is [my code](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35353772#35353772).Help please.

Comment: @yode I have no experience with this API but it seems you've already got the answer: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35358667#35358667

Comment: I am a little confused. To what extent imgur is blocked by GFW? Why can you see pictures from imgur on SE, while a direct access is impossible?

Comment: @happyfish `"http://stackoverflow.com/upload/image"` is a extra port for *StackEchange*,but not a opening API,I think.

Comment: I guess that upload API just acts like a web proxy. But I meant the images you can see on SE, they should be hosted directly by imgur, wouldn't that imply imgur is not blocked?

Comment: @happyfish No,imgur is not blocked,they just forbid their API is called by Chinese mainland user.

Comment: Perhaps we need a special toolkit for Chinese users. I remember having trouble logging in without VPN.

Comment: @happyfish Yes,we cannot logging in sometimes or some places.

Answer (score 3):

You can store limited amounts of data as QR images as I used here:

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/73088/363

You don't need to scan them; the data can be retrieved from the image URL.

Comment: As the documentatation,the character limited size seem too small?

Comment: Yes, it's limited. In the example linked, I tried putting the dates and two data sets in one QR file but it was too big, so I split it.