# How can one best post a long answer to a Mathematica Stack Exchange Question?

Tags: discussion

In trying to help a user with a question (see [293958](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/293850)), I ran his code and after a relatively lengthy running time demonstrated that his code does indeed get an answer.  However, the answer is quite a lengthy expression.

Since his code is apparently not running on his machine, it makes little sense to simply repost his code as an answer to his question  In a comment, he asks for the answer, which is quite lengthy.

**Is simply pasting the expression into the answer the best way to answer his question, or is there a more appropriate method on Mathematica Stack Exchange to communicate a lengthy answer (expression) in response?**

I hope I am correctly posting this to the Meta section discussion.

Comment: In general, these questions should be closed as "off topic" as it is detailed code specific to their problem and there isn't future value to others. I also get the desire to help the OP, so here are some options: 1) paste the expression as an answer if it fits 2) use Github/Gists/Dropbox to share the notebook if it is longer or 3) try one of the other exotic ideas [here](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2145/5). Once you do that, I propose the question ought to be closed and deleted.

Comment: I'll try approach 2, so this post can be ignored.  I had thought that posting to Meta would be the place where issues such as this could be consulted to serve as a guide to appropriate action for future users.  In this sense, i don't understand the purpose of  Meta if such questions and follow-up guidance are to be deleted as off-topic.

Comment: Your question is perfectly fine on meta. I was referring to the question (on main) that you linked to as off-topic.

Comment: Perhaps there might usefully be a place where such problem specific issues can be addressed.  MMA doesn't always execute as expected and on occasion it can crash, leading one to be unsure if its a problem with a specific implementation on a specific platform or some kind of fault in MMA settings or in MMA itself.  I have yet to experience the latter.